# AutoCompleteTextView set one item in textView after selected on row which contained 2 items

Tags: android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview, multiautocompletetextview

My problem on my code below:

The autocomplete worked properly and show me phone and Name, but I need only phone put one textview after selection.

Please.

```
  public class SendingSMSActivity extends Activity{
    private int mCount;
    private AutoCompleteTextView actv;
    private ArrayList<String> mcurrentssFistLastName_PhoneList = null;
   // private ArrayList<String> mcurrentssFistLastNameList = null;

    AutoCompleteTextView PhoneNumberAutoComp;
    MultiAutoCompleteTextView PhoneNumberMultiAutoComp;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sending_sms_activity);
        PhoneNumberAutoComp=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.aCT_phone_number);
        PhoneNumberMultiAutoComp=(MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.multiCompTextView);



        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,init());


        PhoneNumberAutoComp.setAdapter(adapter);
        PhoneNumberAutoComp.setThreshold(1);

        PhoneNumberMultiAutoComp.setAdapter(adapter);
        PhoneNumberMultiAutoComp.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

    }




    private ArrayList<String> init(){
        mcurrentssFistLastName_PhoneList = new ArrayList<String>();
        //mcurrentssFistLastNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        InnerDB db = new InnerDB(SendingSMSActivity.this);

        final ArrayList<String> sPhoneList = db.getAllPhoneNumber();
        final ArrayList<String> sFirstLastNameList = db.getAllSFirstName();
        mCount = sPhoneList.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < mCount; i ++){
            mcurrentssFistLastName_PhoneList.add(sFirstLastNameList.get(i) +" " +sPhoneList.get(i));
            //mcurrentssFistLastNameList.add(sFirstLastNameList.get(i));
        }

        return mcurrentssFistLastName_PhoneList;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();



    }
}
```